# Guardar imagen con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

**Al intentar guardar una imagen desde mi formulario, recibo el siguiente error:**

**> Call to a member function store() on null**

Es asi como estoy intentando subir y almacenar una imagen

**Mi formulario: (agregue 'files' => true,  y el input del tipo file)**

```
<div class="row">
{!! Form::model($user, [
    'route' => $user->exists ? ['admin.users.update', $user->id] : 'admin.users.store',   
    'files' => true, 
    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',   
    'method' => $user->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST'
]) !!}

 <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Perfil</h3>                
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">                   
                <img width="300px" class="profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle" 
                    src="{{ Storage::url($user->user_photo)}}"                  
                    alt="{{ $user->name}}">
                    &nbsp;
                    &nbsp;
                <div class="form-group">              
                {!! Form::label('user_photo', 'Imagen de Perfil') !!}                    
                {!! Form::file('user_photo') !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div> 
{!! Form::close() !!}    
</div>
```

**Mi controlador UserController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Statu;
use DataTables;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Providers\UserWasCreated;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Requests\SaveUserRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {   
        $user = new User();      
                             
        return view('admin.users.partials.form', [
            'genders'   => User::pluck('gender', 'gender'),
            'provinces' => User::pluck('province','province'),
            'status'    => Statu::pluck('state_description', 'id'),           
            'user'      => $user
        ]);  
    }
    public function store(SaveUserRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){
            try {
                //  Transacciones
                DB::beginTransaction();

                // Creamos el usuario            
                $user = new User;   
                $user->name         = $request->get('name');
                $user->surname      = $request->get('surname');
                $user->nickname     = $request->get('nickname');
                $user->email        = $request->get('email');        
                $user->password     = $request->get('password');
                $user->gender       = $request->get('gender');  
                $user->address      = $request->get('address');
                $user->postcode     = $request->get('postcode');  
                $user->city         = $request->get('city');
                $user->province     = $request->get('province');  
                $user->phone        = $request->get('phone');
                $user->birthdate    = Carbon::parse($request->get('birthdate'));                      
                $user->status_id    = $request->get('status_id');            
               

                if ($request->hasFile('user_photo'))
                {
                    $user->user_photo = $request->file('user_photo')->store('public');
                }
                $user->save();
                
                // Enviamos el email
                // UserWasCreated::dispatch($user, $data['password']);
                //$user->update($request->validated()); 
    
                DB::commit();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // anula la transacion
                DB::rollBack();
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comento que he ejecutado el siguiente comando  **php artisan storage:link**

La verdad no puedo darme cuenta donde esta mi error, les agradezco su AYUDA!

**Actualizado 1:**

inspeccionado observo lo siguiente:

```
if ($request->hasFile('user_photo'))
                {
                    $user->user_photo = $request->file('user_photo')->store('public');
                }
                dd($request->file('user_photo'));
                $user->save();
```

en la consola veo que llega null, no toma la imagen que selecciono al momento de crear un usuario

**Actualizado 2**

Quisas esto no me está andando en el formulario 'files' => true,
’enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', ?; Justamente cuando inspeccióno observo que llega null

```
<div class="row">
{!! Form::model($user, [
    'route' => $user->exists ? ['admin.users.update', $user->id] : 'admin.users.store',   
    'files' => true, 
    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',   
    'method' => $user->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST'
]) !!}
```

Comment: estas haciendo una doble insercion de la imagen en tu if y antes de

Comment: De igual modo a tu formulario le falta el `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @Dohko19 Si recien lo he verificado, he elimando la doble insercion, y he agregado ```enctype="multipart/form-data"``` de todas maneras ahora, guarda el registro PERO NO GUARDA LA IMAGEN, en mi tabla user el campo user_photo es null

Comment: y la imagen si la guarda?

Comment: al principio de la funcion agrega ddd($request->file('user_photo'); y comenta lo que muestra

Comment: vi que usas vuiejs o js, entonces solo ser dd()

Comment: @Dohko19 ejecute la linea al principio y llega null, anteriormente quise decir que en tabla usuario se guardar los campos, pero el campo user_photo en la cual debe guardar la imagen, llega null y directamente no esta almacenado la imagen